# Facebook App Instance Settings

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I have an app that needs to have unique settings to each instance of a user adding it to their page (it is made to be added as a tab).

I have not been able to find any documentation to do this -- does anyone know how? Or does anyone have an example to follow or a place to learn?

---

SOLUTION

I made a section on the Tab for the app user's page that only shows to admin's of Page. It links to a page in my app sending the `page_id` to my page. This allows me to now store information (and settings) in my database based off the `page_id`.

I found that Facebook has a section to go to an App's settings page (which you can set up in your application settings via the Developer App) which also sends the page_id -- but it doesn't send it in an encrypted sense, so I encrypted the page_id with my settings option.

If anyone needs further explanation, feel free to message me I would be happy to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you are looking for is the "page" instance. Every page has a Facebook ID just like every user does. For the most part, you can use a page ID anywhere you would a user ID. What you want to do is capture the ID of the page, not the ID of the user adding it to the page (the admin). Scroll almost all the way to the bottom if this URL to see how to grab the page ID:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/

Basically, an additional parameter is included call "page" that will contain the page ID. Use that to interact with the page and store any session information.

Comment: Hi Brent -- I've read that page many times and I know how to get the page id and so on, but how do I set settings related to it based of the owner of the user? Perspective from the user: I install the app, I want to set settings on my page (but the page ID can't be gotten from that page). Would creating an admin settings link work from the tab that sends them back to the other page (with the page_id) work?

Comment: The "owner of the user"? In the "page" section, there will be an "id" parameter, which is the id of the page. If the user viewing the page has authorized your app, there will be a "user_id" item in the signed request. There will also be a "user" section, where you can tell if they are an admin or not. Based on that, you could "reveal" additional options. I'm not sure what "other page" you are referring to. There are only 2 ids, the current page ID and the current user ID.

Comment: - right , and they are not sent in any one page. The page id is only sent on the page (not the settings page), and the user id is only sent on the settings page (reliably).

Comment: What settings page are you referring to? The only "setting" a page admin can change for an added app is the tab name.

Comment: Going to give you the bounty and I will detail my solution in my post as you guided me to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use database to store the settings of each instance of a user, with a unique key (use php's uniqid function).

App can retrieve the settings based on key with respect to the user.

Comment: I know I can do one for each instance of the user, but I don't want each instance of a user, I want each instance of my app. The difference is, when my app is added as a tab to someone's Page, and other users view that tab -- that counts as a user seeing it. I only need to store information for the people who add the app -- not those who see the tab.

Answer (score 1):

When a user goes to your app by accessing a tab in another page your app receives a POST var called `signed_request`.

In PHP, this var can me decoded by the following way:

```
function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
  list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

  // decode the data
  $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
  $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

  if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
    error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
    return null;
  }

  // check sig
  $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
  if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
    error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
    return null;
  }

  return $data;
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
}

$arr = parse_signed_request($_POST["signed_request"], "YOUR_APP_SECRET");

echo print_r($arr);
```

Probably you can use the $arr["page"]["id"] to know which page accessed your app.

You can read more about that here:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi Raphael -- thanks for the answer. I am fully aware of the signed request and of the page id, but how do I relate that to settings, as the page ID is *not* sent to the main app page, where I have settings. Is there another way to do settings or the like?